# PostgreSQL - how to create critical section in function

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency, locking

I need to lock row for one user to prevent from changing content by any other.

```
User A: call function lock_row() to lock row X
User B: call function lock_row() to lock row X (lock cant be created and "exception" should be triggered as row X is already locked)
```

There cant be the case when users A and B are connected using the same session.

So how to ensure that something like that wont happened:

```
User A: check if lock == 0
User B: check if lock == 0
User A: lock == 0 so SET lock = 1
User B: lock == 0 is also here so SET lock = 1
```

I would like to create lock not directly on SQL statement by trigger (UPDATE on row) but rather by function to allow users release lock in case of unexpected errors.

How to create "critical section"? How to ensure that critical section in my function will be executed properly?

PostgreSQL version 9.x.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS

Comment: Major Postgres versions include the first digit after the dot. There is no version "9.x", it's 9.4 or 9.5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an ***exclusive [row lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) in the same transaction***.
Add **`NOWAIT`** to make the transaction fail immediately if the lock can't be acquired (locked by another transaction).

```
BEGIN;

SELECT 1
FROM   tbl
WHERE  tbl_id = x
FOR    UPDATE NOWAIT;

- do something

COMMIT; -- lock released automatically
```

Depending on what you are planning to do, the less restrictive `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` may be good enough.

Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

Optionally, you can wrap the `SELECT` or the complete transaction into a function. Same effect. An exception always skips the whole transaction (unless you trap the error).

Advisory locks are another option, but less reliable. There is no need to fall back to this generic tool, when you can achieve the same with row level locks.

Comment: Can i use it with hibernate 5? (or just creating my own SQL statements which i would rather avoid)

Comment: @BartekSzczypien: I am an expert with Postgres. Not sure about Hibernate.